# Show different divs and add class if div is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggleclass

I want to show a div depending on which link is clicked.

If btn1 is clicked, **link1 should get the class="activemenu"** and div1 should be shown. If btn1 is clicked again, the class should be removed and the div be hidden.

If btn2 is clicked the same should happen for div2.

If one div is opened already (e.g. div1 is visible because btn1 was clicked), div1 should hide and the class should be removed from btn1 and be added to btn2 and div2 should show up.

The same should happen with btn3 and div3.

The divs are shown **correctly**, but the **class** wont be added or removed.

HTML:

```
<div> 
 <a class="trigger" id="btn1" href="#box1"> Heading 1</a>
 <a class="trigger" id="btn2"  href="#box2"> Heading 2</a>
 <a class="trigger" id="btn3" href="#box3"> Heading 2</a>
</div>
<div class ="toggle" id="box1">box one content</div>
<div class ="toggle" id="box2">box two content</div>
<div class ="toggle" id="box3">box three content</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {float:left;padding:20px}
h3 {font-size:2em; curser:pointer;}
div.toggle{display: none;}
.activemenu{font-size: 100px;}
```

JS:

```
$("a").click(function(){
  var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
  $(myelement).slideToggle("slow");
  $(myelement).toggleClass("activemenu");
  $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();
});
```

[Demo Code (not working properly)](http://jsfiddle.net/CkTRa/2588/)

Thank you very much

Comment: in your CSS change `activemenu` to `.activemenu`. Classes are selected with a `.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I understand your requirement and my mistake, here is that line :

```
$('.trigger:not(#'+this.id+')').removeClass("activemenu");
```

Also changed `myelement` to `this`

```
$(this).toggleClass("activemenu");
```

So, it will remove `activemenu` class from all toggle divs and after then you can add the same class again.

here is the [updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/CkTRa/2600/)

```
$("a").click(function(){
   var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
   $(myelement).slideToggle("slow");
   $('.trigger:not(#'+this.id+')').removeClass("activemenu");
   $(this).toggleClass("activemenu");
   $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();
});
```

Comment: The whole point of `toggleClass` is to save you from the responsibility of manually writing `addClass`/`removeClass`. :) Sure, this would work but then don't you think this is violating the spirit behind the `toggleClass` API? :)

Comment: violating the spirit, @AdityaParab? Has our reverence for jQuery grown so much that we now run the risk of blaspheming against it?

Comment: Okay, I tried to use the correct code on the website but jQuery throws 
**Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:** at me

Comment: Please mate.. Do not confuse `spirit`/`soul` with `religion`. :) Those two are two completely different things. Although commonly confused but they have nothing to do with one another.

Answer (score 2):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CkTRa/2601/)

Use `$(this)` to select the clicked element

```
    $("a").click(function(){
   var myelement = $(this).attr("href")
    $(myelement).slideToggle("slow");

        $(this).toggleClass("activemenu");
    $(".trigger").not($(this)).removeClass("activemenu");
    $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();

  });
```

Comment: Still it is wrong.. it is not removing `activemenu` class after clicking again.. check my updated answer

Comment: also working code, thank you
but jQuery still throws me an exception:
**Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /gasthof/speisekarten/#div1**

Comment: when I click the link to show the div
http://krieger.nmptest.de/gasthof/speisekarten

Comment: @sebi : change `href="gasthof/speisekarten/#div2"  to href="#div2"` and same for `div1`

Comment: `<a class="trigger" id="btn1" href="#div1"><f:format.raw>{WOCHENTAGSKARTE}</f:format.raw></a>  `




this is the code in my HTML, gasthof/speisekarten/#div2 is made by typo3 i think

Answer (score 0):

First remove the class from all `.toogle` elements.

```
$("a").click(function() {
  var myelement = this.href;
  $(myelement).slideToggle("slow");
  $(this).addClass('activemenu').siblings().removeClass("activemenu");
  $(myelement).toggleClass("activemenu");
  $(".toggle:visible").not(myelement).hide();
});
```

Also add the proper CSS selector. `.activemenu`, you were using without `.` operator.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/do4s86q4/5/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CkTRa/2593/ Updated Demo
Its adding the class to the div, not the btn1/btn2/btn2

Comment: @sebi I did not get you.

Comment: check the answer below, this is what should happen when the link is clicked the link should get bold/bigger font size not the content of the div element ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your css entry I wrong. Put '.' Before activemenu

Comment: Good spot. But not completely solve the issue. Upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a data-box and simply show them like that :

```
<a class = "trigger" id="btn1" data-box="box1" href="#box1"> Heading 1</a> 
<a class="trigger" id="btn2" data-box="box2"  href="#box2"> Heading 2</a>
<a class="trigger" id="btn3" data-box="box3" href="#box3"> Heading 2</a>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
  var element=$("#"+$(this).data("box"));
  element.toggle();
  $(".activemenu").removeClass("activemenu");
  $(element).toggleClass("activemenu");
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CkTRa/2597/)